# Passing NULL for array parameter in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, null

```
void DoSomeThing(CHAR parm[])
{

}

int main()
{
    DoSomeThing(NULL);
}
```

Is the passing NULL for array parameter allowed in C/C++?

Comment: That's why we have compilers :). Write the code in a file and try to compile it. gcc input.c or g++ input.cpp

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I think you missed the distinction between 'possible' and 'allowed'

Comment: "Try it" is a good first shot, but especially in the realm of C and C++ with its hundreds of compiler-specific language extensions, he who wants portability has to ask the language lawyers. Not that this is a particular great question.

Comment: @reader:  No, that's why we have *Specifications*.  Just because it compiles doesn't mean it's allowed.

Comment: @JohnDibling -- And just because it's allowed doesn't mean it compiles.

Comment: @JohnDibling I think compilers allow things or reject things, specifications tell how things should be. You can't compile a program with a specification. If the question was is is a valid use then we would definitely look at the specification. Look at this post: http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2009-June/020620.html The specification writer updated the specification because although things should be according to specifications but it is not the case in the real world.

Comment: @reader: That is a strawman argument.  C++ is a compiled language.  You are proposing that we should determine if something is a legal & valid C++ construct by attempting to compile & run it.  If it compiles and does what you expect, it's legal.  Otherwise it's not.  Then you say that we shouldn't bother to look to the Specs because they don't reflect the real world, and as evidence you bring forth a non-compiled scripting language that doesn't produce bytecode.  There is no relevance between the patent landscape of Ogg and determining the validity of a C++ construct by compiling it.

Comment: @JohnDibling You are not reading what I am saying. So it is best to stop here.

Comment: ... Some C++ constructs are syntactically valid but are still invalid.  A classic example: `int j = i++ + i++;".  Syntactically valid & will compile.  If you run it in the debugger it might even "work."  But it's still invalid.  It might not even work in the same compiler if you compile it in Release mode.

Comment: I have read what you've said several times.  If you would care to clarify your position, I'll read that too.

Comment: What I wrote in my previous comment: "If the question was is is a valid use then we would definitely look at the specification." (although there is a typo in it). So I am not telling that we need to ignore specs. We need to look at them to see what is valid or not and how things should be. Therefore we are not opposed to each other in this view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you cannot do is pass an array by value. The signature of the function

```
void f( char array[] );
```

is transformed into:

```
void f( char *array );
```

and you can always pass NULL as argument to a function taking a pointer.

You can however pass an array by reference in C++, and in that case you will not be able to pass a NULL pointer (or any other pointer):

```
void g( char (&array)[ 10 ] );
```

Note that the size of the array is part of the type, and thus part of the signature, which means that `g` will only accept *lvalue-expressions* of type *array of 10 characters*

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is *yes*, you can pass NULL in this instance (at least for C, and I *think* the same is true for C++).

There are two reasons for this.  First, in the context of a function parameter declaration, the declarations `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are synonymous with `T *a`; IOW, despite the array notation, `a` is declared as a *pointer* to `T`, rather than an array of `T`.  From the C language [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression.

The second reason is that when an expression of array type appears in most contexts (such as in a function call), the type of that expression is implicitly converted ("decays") to a pointer type, so what actually gets passed to the function is a pointer value, not an array:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what you're passing to the function is a *pointer* and not an *array*. The array notation used for the `parm` parameter is just syntactic sugar for `CHAR *parm`.

So yes, you can pass a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue would be if DoSomeThing were overloaded, in which case the compiler might not be able to distinguish which function to call.  But casting to the appropriate type would theoretically fix that.